# How to get page type in page.html.twig

Tags: theming

I need to set some classes in page.html.twig based on page type (node, view, etc..) and if possible in more details (node type 'article', view 'blog') etc.

some ideas how to do this? I can't figure out how to get that done in page.html.twig?!

thank you! 
Matthias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no page type in Drupal 8. But you can get the route name in a page preprocess hook to identify the type of page:

**Route name**

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['route_name'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
}
```

and in twig:

```
{{ route_name }}
```

**Route parameters**

For route parameters:

```
 if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
```

This code for the node is already in `theme.inc`, so you can use it right away in twig to get the content type:

```
{{ node.gettype }}
```

The node is the only route parameter that is loaded by default. You have to get parameters from other routes in preprocess, for example the view id and display id from a view route:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['view_id'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id');
  $variables['display_id'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('display_id');
}
```

Comment: that works great! I never now how to search for stuff like that.. can't read that API docs.

Answer (score 1):

Far out

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')
```

returns the nid instead of a node object on the node/[nid]/revisions/[vid]/view pages so if you do anything like

```
$node->bundle()
```

you get a WSOD

Comment: +1, so good practice would be to check the route name first before you get route parameters, see for example this issue in a contrib theme https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_mint/issues/2918947

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me to get the node type.

In mytheme_preprocess_page():

```
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['content_type'] = $node->bundle();
  }
```

Then I checked if `content_type` is == to what I want in page.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add a follow up since this question was asked a long time ago and Drupal evolves!

If you take a look at `core/modules/system/templates/page.html.twig` in the doc comments under **Page Content** lines ~23 - 28;

```
 * - node: Fully loaded node, if there is an automatically-loaded node
 *   associated with the page and the node ID is the second argument in the
 *   page's path (e.g. node/12345 and node/12345/revisions, but not
 *   comment/reply/12345).
```

So you can actually access the full node without any preprocessing, its right there in the twig template for you. Give it a try with;

```
{{ node.getType() }}
```